# LM2664 can I use the ceramic capacitors instead of the electrolytic ones?

Tags: capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor, charge-pump, ceramic, negative-voltage

I need the negative voltage for my OPAMP and I use the LM2664 inverter. I have a very limited space available on my PCB. Is it OK to replace the electrolytic capacitors with the ceramic ones?

Comment: There is a selection on capacitor selection in the datasheet, but ultimately it looks like it's happy with low ESR, so ceramic caps should be ok.

Comment: Strange, but where do you find ceramic caps that are smaller than elec. caps for the same capacitance.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič  for example here http://uk.farnell.com/c/passive-components/capacitors/ceramic-capacitors?capacitance=3.3uf&ceramic-capacitor-case=0402-1005-metric-

Comment: Why invent warm water, if they provided the EVAL board with all details for caps and design.

Answer (score 6):

I've had a look through the datasheet and all it seems to say about the capacitors is that they must have a low ESR. I can't find anywhere that it specifies a minimum ESR or states that they must be electrolytic.

Therefore, I think you can safety use ceramic capacitors as these have a very low ESR.

Hypothetically, if the datasheet did require a *minimum* ESR (as some devices do), you could still use a ceramic capacitor instead. All you'd have to do is place a small resistor in series with the ceramic capacitor (around 0.5 ohms, or whatever value the minimum is in the datasheet).